# GetLogicalDriveString c++

Tags: c++, windows

Estoy tratando de listar todos los discos que tiene instalado el sistema mediante la función  GetLogicalDriveString, no tengo conocimientos sobre los tipos de Windows (DWORD,LPWSTR...) por lo que ando un poco perdido. Tengo la siguiente implementación

```
std::vector<TCHAR> getLogicalDrives()
{

    DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
    TCHAR szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    std::vector<TCHAR> disks;

    DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize, szLogicalDrives);

    if (dwResult > 0 && dwResult <= MAX_PATH)
    {
        TCHAR* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives;
        while (*szSingleDrive)
        {
            disks.push_back(*szSingleDrive);
            // get the next drive
            szSingleDrive += StringCchLength(szSingleDrive, dwSize, NULL) + 1; //Es esto correcto?
        }
    }

    return disks;
}
```

Si pongo el juego de caracteres en multibyte el código funciona, pero he visto por internet que es mejor programar con unicode, y e aquí el problema. Al tratar de compilar me da un error, "char * no es compatible con LPWSTR". Es la variable szLogicalDrives la que falla.

Tengo el mismo problema también con otras funciones como GetModuleFileName.

He estado buscando pero no encuentro ninguna solución, alguien me podría ayudar?

Si pudierais decirme también porque es mejor programar en Unicode que en Multibyte os lo agradecería

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows tiene redefinidas todas las *APIs*, de forma que puedas escribir un único código fuente y ese código pueda compilarse como unicode o como no unicode.

Cuando llamas a algo como `GetModuleFileName`, así tal cual, dependiendo de la configuración de tu proyecto, realmente estarás llamando a la función `GetModuleFileNameA` si no usas unicode, o a `GetModuleFileNameW` si usas unicode. Parece un poco lioso, pero es por facilitar las cosas.

El problema es que cada versión de la función recibe tipos de datos diferentes. Para las versiones `A` usa `LPSTR`, lo que es lo mismo a `char*` (1 byte por char). Para las versiones `W` usa `LPWSTR`, lo que es lo mismo que `wchar_t*` (2 bytes por char).

¿Entonces, cómo haces para llamar a `GetModuleFileName` sin tener que cambiar el tipo del parámetro si compilas en Unicode o no? Pues usando las macros y redefiniciones de tipos que tienen los includes de Windows.

Para definir un tipo `char*` o `wchar_t*` en función de la configuración de unicode del proyecto, puedes usar el tipo `TCHAR`. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
TCHAR * lpName = new TCHAR[20];
DWORD nsize = 20;
GetModuleFileName( hModule, lpName, nSize);
```

Este código compilaría tanto en unicode como en no unicode y es porque `TCHAR` está redefinido como `wchar_t` cuando configuras el proyecto para usar unicode, o como `char` cuando lo configuras para no usarlo.

Para las cadenas constantes que quieras pasar a una función, puedes usar la macro `_T()` de la siguiente forma:

```
const TCHAR * lpTem = _T( "Hola");
```

Igual que en el ejemplo anterior, esto se sustituiría en unicode por:

```
const wchar_t * lpTemp = L"Hola";
```

y en no unicode por:

```
const char * lpTemp = "Hola";
```

Usando estas macros y tipos de datos, puedes escribir todo el código una sola vez y hacer que funcione tanto en unicode como en no unicode.

Siempre podrías usar directamente la llamada con la `A` o la `W`, pero entonces al cambiar la configuración de tu proyecto, no compilaría. También podrías asumir que tu proyecto no va a compilarse nunca no unicode, usar las funciones sin `A` ni `W` y definir todo directamente como `wchar_t` en vez de `char`. Eso haría también que no compile sin unicode.

En definitiva, una vez sabes lo que hay, eres libre de usar lo que creas más conveniente, pensando en la evolución futura de tu proyecto.

**Añadido tras la modificación en la pregunta:**

No entiendo muy bien para qué quieres guardar los resultados en un vector de `TCHAR`. El resultado de la función `GetLogicalDriveStrings` retorna una cadena de caracteres con todas las unidades, cada una separada de la siguiente por un `\0` y con dos `\0` al final. Algo como esto: `"C:\\0E:\\0F:\\0\0"`. Lo que imagino que querrás es extraer las cadenas separadas: `"C:\"`, `"E:\"`, `"F:\"`. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
TCHAR szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize, szLogicalDrives);

if (dwResult > 0 && dwResult <= MAX_PATH)
{
    TCHAR* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives;
    while (*szSingleDrive)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Drive: %s\n"), szSingleDrive);

        // get the next drive
        szSingleDrive += _tcslen(szSingleDrive) + 1;
    }
}
```

Usando las funciones `_tprintf` y `_tcslen` te olvidas de si trabajas en `wchar_t` o en `char` y este código compila tanto configurando unicode como no unicode.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Ahora entiendo mejor los tipos pero sigo teniendo problemas con mi código. A la hora de insertar los TCHAR dentro de un vector, y tener que coger la longitud del TCHAR para moverme hacia la siguiente unidad, no se como hacerlo. También tengo problemas a la hora de imprimir por consola los valores del vector, voy a modificar el código de la pregunta para ver si me puedes decir cómo lo ves o qué cambiarías

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por seguir el hilo, el vector lo necesito para usar las unidades en otras funciones, por eso necesito que retorne un vector con todas las unidades. Pero bueno con tu respuesta creo que podre terminar adaptándolo para devolver un vector de TCHAR. Gracias de nuevo.